# I need to implement a setting in default navigation drawer as like as fragment

Tags: android-studio, android-fragments, android-intent

This is a navigation fragment layout and I need to implement the setting as a fragment. Like as when I click the settings then it shows setting as like what fragment work as:

[image]

Code:

```
    private void ShowFragment(int itemId) {

        Fragment fragment = null;

        switch (itemId) {
            case R.id.nav_Weapons:
                fragment = new Weapons();
                break;

            case R.id.nav_Ammo_types:
                fragment = new Ammo_Types();
                break;


            case R.id.nav_Attachments:
                fragment = new Attachments();
                break;

            case R.id.Throwables:
                fragment = new Throwables();
                break;

            case R.id.Health_Items:
                fragment = new Health_Items();
                break;


            case R.id.Maps:
                fragment = new Maps();
                break;

            case R.id.nav_share:
                Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");
                sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Text");
                sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Subject");
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share using"));
                break;

            case R.id.action_settings:
                fragment = new settings();
                break;
```

Comment: Can you share the complete source code of your MainActivity.java and settings.java ?

Answer (score 1):

if you are using AppcompactActivity,

```
... // other codes
case R.id.action_settings:
                fragment = new settings();
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment, fragment.toString())
                .addToBackStack(null)
                .commit()
                break;
```

Comment: Cannot resolve method "getsupportFragmentManager"

Comment: I have edited my answer, Intellij will show you some suggestions, choose the one similar... if you have any problem let me know